# Performance of TThreadPool degrades with time?

Tags: multithreading, performance, delphi, threadpool

The following code begins at ~70% cpu usage (according to task manager), but after a few minutes degrades to less than 20% -- this type of behavior occurs irrespective of the code run by the tasks (actual % values will differ, obviously).

Re-creating the threadpool makes it go back up to 70% again.

A bug in Delphi or expected behavior I am unaware of? Is there a way to fix/mitigate this (other than the workaround of repeatedly re-creating the threadpool)?

**EDIT: 10.4 bug, 11.3 indeed behaves differently (also more efficient: ~80% cpu)**

```
type
  TParallel = class(TThread)
  strict protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

var
  Parallel: TParallel;
  Recreate: Boolean;

procedure TParallel.Execute;

  function Task(const ThreadPool: TThreadPool): ITask;
  begin
    Result := TTask.Create(
      procedure
      const
        N = 10000;
      var
        I: Integer;
      begin
        for I := 1 to N do
          Random(10000); // example; meaningless code
      end, ThreadPool);
  end;

const
  N = 12; // arbitrary number
var
  I: Integer;
  Tasks: TArray<ITask>;
  ThreadPool: TThreadPool;
begin
  Randomize;
  ThreadPool := TThreadPool.Create;
  SetLength(Tasks, N);
  try
    while not Terminated do begin
      if Recreate then begin
        Recreate := False;
        ThreadPool.Free;
        ThreadPool := TThreadPool.Create;
      end;
      for I := 0 to N - 1 do begin
        Tasks[I] := Task(ThreadPool);
        Tasks[I].Start;
      end;
      TTask.WaitForAll(Tasks);
    end;
  finally
    ThreadPool.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Parallel = nil then
    Parallel := TParallel.Create(False);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button8Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Parallel <> nil then
    FreeAndNil(Parallel);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button9Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Recreate := True;
end;
```

Comment: Cannot repro with 11.3 on an i5-13600K

Comment: Stefan Glienke: (10.4 & i5-10600K here) just reproduced on another computer. perhaps your computer is faster and thus higher `N`s are required?

Comment: Stefan Glienke: 10.4 bug, 11.3 indeed behaves differently (also more efficient: ~80% cpu)

Comment: I would recommend against using of `Random` calls as meaningless code for any thread based benchmarking purposes. Why? `Randomize` is not a thread safe function as it is relying on some global variables like [RandSeed](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.RandSeed). Instead you should have used just some arithmetic calculations. While this should not be the cause for the problem you are observing you do want to avoid any uncertainties when doing any kind of benchmarkings.